# keep focus on canvas Layer after map drag

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I have a L.canvasMarker from [leaflet-canvas-markers](https://github.com/eJuke/Leaflet.Canvas-Markers#readme)

When in editing mode with [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman) I can move the marker without any issue.
But if I drag the map then try to drag the marker, it does not work (it has lost focus).
To be able to drag it again I have to click it first, then I can drag it normally again.

My attempt of fixing this was to get the DOM element of the marker then fire focus() event.
But I dont know how to get access to a leaflet layer DOM element.

my attempt of fixing below:

```
map.on('moveend', function(e) { 
    marker.getContainer() //getContainer does not work on layer
    marker.getContainer().setAttribute('tabindex', '0')
    marker.getContainer().focus()
    })
```

Also snapping from leaflet-geoman does not work, but I guess a change in the snapping calculation has to be made for this to work. Which is a complete seperate issue.

Here is a fiddle: move the marker -> Drag the map -> try to move the marker again.

https://jsfiddle.net/nkmtLdc5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a issue of leaflet v1.6.0 and only is not working in chrome.

When you update the leaflet to v1.7.1 it works.

Replace your leaflet.js cdn url with this: https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js

Comment: This has something to do with the `mousedown` or `mousemove` event in leaflet core. I can't test for you because I don't have safari, so i'm out ... But I suggest you to find a way to reproduce this with leaflet alone and then create a bug ticket on github in the leaflet repo